# SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for || Undefined variable: suffix

Tags: php

i have a problem in my code. When i post something then it displays:

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: suffix in...

But i have defined my variable in my code... So how i can fix this error?

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test", $conn);
$time = time();

if(isset($_POST['pateikti'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['tekstas'])) { echo "Tekstas per trumpas!"; }
    else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tsp (timestamp, text) VALUES ('".time()."', '$_POST[tekstas]')");
    }
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tsp");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $diff = $time - $row['timestamp'];

    switch(1) {
            case ($diff < 60):
        $ago = $diff;
        if($ago == 0)
            $ago == "akimirką";
        else if($diff < 10)
            $suffix = "sekundes";
        else
            $suffix = "sekundžių";
        break;

    }

        echo $row['text']." buvo parasytas prieš ".$diff." ".$suffix."</br>";

}

?>

<form action="" method="POST" >
    <input type="text" name="tekstas" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="pateikti" value="Pateikti" />
</form>
```

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Comment: Where have you defined it? Only in two of the three `ìf`/`else` branches, or not?

Comment: Define `$suffix='';` __before__ your `switch` statement

Answer (score 1):

since you do not define it before the switch then use a default to set it in case  diff is greater than 60

```
switch(1) {
    case ($diff < 60):
       $ago = $diff;
       if($ago == 0)
          $ago == "akimirką";
       else if($diff < 10)
          $suffix = "sekundes";
       else
          $suffix = "sekundžių";
    break;
    default:
          $suffix ="default text";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following switch:

```
switch(1) {
        case ($diff < 60):
    $ago = $diff;
    if($ago == 0)
        $ago == "akimirką";
    else if($diff < 10)
        $suffix = "sekundes";
    else
        $suffix = "sekundžių";
    break;

}
```

Here, if `$diff` is equal to `0`, you have that `$suffix` never gets defined.

Simply change the switch to:

```
$suffix = ''; // <-- define "suffix"

switch(1) {
  case ($diff < 60):
    $ago = $diff;
    if($ago == 0)
        $ago == "akimirką";
    else if($diff < 10)
        $suffix = "sekundes";
    else
        $suffix = "sekundžių";
  break;
}
```

Also, IMHO, that switch could be replaced with:

```
$suffix = '';

if($diff < 60) {
  $ago = $diff;

  if($ago == 0) {
    $ago == "akimirką";
  }
  else if($ago < 10) {
    $suffix = "sekundes";
  }
  else {
    $suffix = "sekundžių";
  }
}
```