# How can i keep the radio button checked and get the value

Tags: php, radio-button

How can i keep the radio button checked after being submit also how to get the value of the radio button?

here's my code so far

```
    <input type="radio" name="Itemtype" id="Ingredient" value="Ingredient" <?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype'])) echo "Checked"; ?>  >
Ingredient
<input type="radio" name="Itemtype" id="Miscellaneous" value="Miscellaneous" <?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype'])) echo "Checked"; ?> >
Miscellaneous
```

also tried using this but it end ups being syntax error &&

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype'])) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Ingredient') echo 'checked="checked" ';?>
 <?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype'])) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Miscellaneous') echo 'checked="checked" ';?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can try this(there is one extra ) remove that ):

<?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Ingredient') echo 'checked="checked" ';?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Miscellaneous') echo 'checked="checked"';?>
```

Or You can simply write:

```
<?php if($_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Ingredient') echo 'checked="checked" ';?>
<?php if($_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Miscellaneous') echo 'checked="checked"';?>
```

Comment: Vikas, is there any chance that radio button will messed up sometimes?
cuz earlier it was alright but now the code: `<?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Ingredient') echo 'checked="checked" ';?>` is not returning checked after i select 1 radio button.
also keeps on error SCREAM:Error suppression ignored for and syntax error Undefined Index on Itemtype can u give me a hand on this one too

Comment: For First you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381368/scream-error-suppression-ignored-for-undefined-variable-suffix, for second just write on top of the page error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);